# Do I have to install numpy in PyCharm everytime I create a new project? (install and not import)

Tags: python, numpy, module, pycharm, package

I installed numpy package in PyCharm, following the default way: File->Settings->Project Interpreter->Click on '+' sign->Type numpy in the search baar->Install. Now, when I am working on a new project and trying to import numpy, it says: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'". Please help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If your project uses a new virtual environment you will have to install any module that is not part of the Python standard library, which includes numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Depends.** Your first `numpy` module likely installed in a virtual environment. Therefore, unless you specify that same virtual environment for your new project, your new project will be unable to access a module installed in a virtual environment it doesn't use.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find support for this feature in PyCharm or in any of the available plugins, but if you're not worried about keeping different dependencies isolated, you do have the option of using the same environment for all your projects.